# Using variable in for statement to cycle through array

Tags: android

I am trying to use the variable declared in the for statement in order to cycle through my array. Is this the correct way of doing this? For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    someArray.add(anotherArray.get(i)
}
```

I want to add the objects from anotherArray to someArray starting at 0 and ending at index 3. Is this the correct way of doing this? Below is my actual code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < warIncrement; i++){
    playerTwoNumber.add(playerOneNumber.get(i));
    playerTwoSuit.add(playerOneSuit.get(i));
    playerTwoNumber.add(playerTwoNumber.get(i));
    playerTwoSuit.add(playerTwoSuit.get(i));
    playerOneNumber.remove(i);
    playerOneSuit.remove(i);
    playerTwoNumber.remove(i);
    playerTwoSuit.remove(i);
    playerTwoWarTV.setText("" + playerTwoWar);
    playerTwoCardsTV.setText("" + playerTwoNumber.size());
    playerOneCardsTV.setText("" + playerOneNumber.size());
    playerOneNumberTV.setText("" + playerOneNumber.size() + "\n" + playerOneNumber);
    playerTwoNumberTV.setText("" + playerTwoNumber.size() + "\n" + playerTwoNumber);
    hideWarCards();
    atWar = false;
    warIncrement = 4;
}
```

The problem I am having is it is not adding/removing the correct indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subList` method for this purpose as in

```
List<String> tempPlayerNumbersToTransfer = playerOneNumber.subList(0,warIncrement);
playerTwoNumber.addAll(tempPlayerNumbersToTransfer);
playerOneNumber.removeAll(tempPlayerNumbersToTransfer);
```

Comment: This code looks a lot more compact and easier to understand than mine so I am definitely going to implement it. Unfortunately I am still in my infancy of coding so I have to try to think of ways to make things work with what I currently have knowledge of. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I swear I am going to create a forum for me to post my questions. As soon as I post I see the simple stupid mistake in my code.

Lets say indexes 0-3 of someArray are 10, 16, 20. The first iteration adds/removes i which is index 0. Now I have removed it and 16 is at index 0. Then I cycle through and add/remove i again which is now 1. Instead of adding/removing 16 that WAS at index 1 I add/remove 20 because it is now at index 1.

To fix this I changed i to 0. This way it moves all objects towards index 0 as it cycles through. First iteration add/remove 10. Now that 10 is gone I want to add 16. 16 is now at index 0 so it adds/removes it etc etc. Hopefully my flaw can assist others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you remove an item, the position of the next item will change. For example

List--------> a b c d   ->  b c d

Position--> 0 1 2 3   ->  0 1 2

int i--------> 0 --------->  1

item-------> a --------->  c

The best way to achive it is by

```
playerTwoNumber.addAll(playerOneNumber.subList(start, end));
playerOneNumber.removeAll(playerOneNumber.subList(start, end));
```